# Creating Visual Studio Solutions that load different Prism Modules / Have a unique configuration file

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, prism

Right now I have a solution that contains all of my Prism Modules, a start-up project, and a configuration file to load all of the modules.

What I would like to do is create various solutions, that only load up the necessary modules, additionally I would like the configuration to be specified at the solution level, so that when I debug, it loads up the proper configuration file.

The only workaround I can think of would be to make a unique 'start-up' project for each solution, that had an appropriate configuration file.

Comment: What are the "necessary modules"? In which case are they necessary?

Comment: "necessary modules" are the modules required for the functionality I plan to be working on, a subset of all the modules written for the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, based on what you are saying maybe create a configuration project for each solution.  No real implementation, but put the configuration file for that solution in there with Build Action = Content and then Copy to Output Directory = Copy Always.  Then you can keep the same startup project in each solution and the configuration project would specify modules to load.

I have not tried this, so just a thought.

Comment: This got me what I was looking for, just not as cleanly as I was hoping.  The copy to the output directory saves it to the Project output directory not the startup project unless I add a reference (which then it would need the reference in all solutions), so startup project didn't get the app config.  Adding a post-build event that copies the app config to the startup project though got the job done it just means the variables build directories need to match: copy $(ProjectDir)app.config $(SolutionDir)\StartupProj\$(OutDir)

Comment: Well, with our Prism projects we push every project to a common build folder.  I would think that would work for you, then the configuraiton file would be copied to the common build folder and you would not have to have a reference.

Comment: It probably would, but at the time being we don't have a build script. (It's on the list) Additionally apparently using an appconfig file didn't work because by default when starting the debugger the appconfig gets re-written for security reasons, so I had to make a separate config file.